# qgis-earthengine: using a local qgis layer feature (e.g. shapefile polygon) as a roi

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I wanted to use a local shapefile polygon as roi; i.e.

```
roi = ee.FeatureCollection("path/to/the/qgis_project_name/polygon_name")
```

but, I got:

> Collection.loadTable: Collection asset
>   'path/to/the/qgis_project_name/polygon_name' not found.

I tried to export a shapefile in Google drive but I also got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import your roi as a shapefile (or kml) with [assets section of Earth Engine Code Editor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing). Another option is to use an [earthengine Command Line Tool](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line)

Comment: is there a way to upload an asset from Google drive to GEE?  The earthengine Command Line Tool shows only how to upload an asset from google cloud.

Comment: No, no way. Try using web interface (code editor)

Comment: @Basile - Sorry to bother you mate but in my case this approach does not work. I have the relevant SHP uploaded into assets in GEE and when I'm trying to get it to load in QGIS it does not work and gives the same error as the OP. It is quite frustrating, just wondering if you can help. Cheers